# QML transitions with multiple (from, to) matches

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a simple QML script with a four states which you go through a cycle, say the states are one, two, three, four.

The transition from one to two and from three to four is the same.

Is there a simple way to define this without duplicating the code for the transition?
This does not work:

```
transitions: Transition {
         from: "one"; to: "two"; 
         from: "three"; to: "four"; 
         ParallelAnimation {
             NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
             ColorAnimation { duration: 500 }
         }
 }
```

From the documentation, it seems there is no way of specifying this but

```
transitions: [ Transition {
             from: "one"; to: "two"; 
             ParallelAnimation {
                 NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
                 ColorAnimation { duration: 500 }
             }
         }, Transition {
             from: "three"; to: "four"; 
             ParallelAnimation {
                 NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
                 ColorAnimation { duration: 500 }
             }
         }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue on a very simple app, it is not a pretty way to do it but the only way I found is like this:

```
transitions: 
    Transition {
         from: "two"; to: "three"; 
         //whatever animation you have for this
    },
    //and obviously any other transitions you may have

    //any transition you don't specify will do this:
    Transition {
         from: "*"; to: "*"; 
         ParallelAnimation {
             NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
             ColorAnimation { duration: 500 }
         }
 }
```

Comment: Yep, not the nicest solution, but goes into the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Hm I figure there is no simple way, your answer was the best 8^)

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse an animation by giving it an id.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 400; height: width

    Column {
        spacing: 20
        Repeater {
            model: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
            Button {
                text: modelData
                onClicked: rect.state = modelData
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        x: 200; y: 0
        width: 60; height: width
        color: "red"

        state: "one"
        states: [
            State { name: "one" },
            State { name: "two" },
            State { name: "three" },
            State { name: "four" }
        ]
        NumberAnimation { id: na1; target: rect; property: "y"; to: 200 }
        NumberAnimation { id: na2; target: rect; property: "y"; to: 0 }
        transitions: [
            Transition { from: "one"; to: "two";  animations: na1 },
            Transition { from: "two"; to: "three";  animations: na2 },
            Transition { from: "three"; to: "four";  animations: na1 },
            Transition { from: "four"; to: "one";  animations: na2 }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if you know the concept of [`default property`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties). In your code, `ParallelAnimation` is assigned to the default property `animations` of the `Transition`, and you can explicitly assign an animation(by it's id) to this default property.